# Passar parâmetros para o controller via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Pessoal não manjo nada de jquery/ajax e queria passar um parametro para o controller.

tenho um modal que abre apenas para perguntar se a pessoa esta ciente do cancelamento onde o único campo que é necessario passar é um hidden com a id do que vai ser excluido.

gostaria de saber tambem como ficar meu controller. estou usando asp net mvc 5.

```js
<script>
    $(function () {              

        jQuery('button.delete').on('click', function () {
            var $row = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
            var $columns = $row.find('td');

            $("#nrotitulo").val($row.find('td:eq(1)').text());
            $("#razao").val($row.find('td:eq(2)').text());
            $("#cnpjtitulo").val($row.find('td:eq(3)').text());
            $("#valortitulo").val($row.find('td:eq(7)').text());
            $row.find('td:eq(8)').text()
            $row.find('td:eq(9)').text()

            var obj = {
            titulonro : $("#nrotitulo").val($row.find('td:eq(1)').text()),
            razaosocial : $("#razao").val($row.find('td:eq(2)').text()),
            titulocnpj : $("#cnpjtitulo").val($row.find('td:eq(3)').text()),
            titulovalor : $("#valortitulo").val($row.find('td:eq(7)').text()),
            systicketID : $row.find('td:eq(8)').text(),
            aditiveID : $row.find('td:eq(9)').text()
            };

            var parametros = JSON.stringify(obj);
                alert('error');
        });

        $("#btn-delete").click(function () {
            alert('ok');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Cliente/TicketDelete',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: parametros,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (parametros) {

                }
            });

    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basta passar o ID no data:**

```
data: { "id": id},
```

**No seu Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetID(int id){ }
```